# Time to take the ATPL and license conversion

Tags: pilot-certification, easa, atpl

How long does it take to get the EASA ATPL license on average? 
And if, after obtaining the ATPL licence in a particular country, you are recruited in a foreign country, do you need to re-take examinations in order to be able to convert it into a valid one in that country, or is the one obtained directly in your own country OK? For example, if you switch from an EASA license to a FAA. 
Thank you